# Multiple errors in 2 lines C++

Tags: c++

I'm having 5 errors in line number 27 and 28 of code:

```
Request * ServerFactory::make_request(int type) {
    if (type == 1)
        return new RequestA(); // line number 27
    else if (type == 2)            // line number 28
        return new RequestB();
    else if (type == 3)
        return new MRRequest();

    return NULL;
}
```

and errors are:

```
1.error: expected type-specifier before ‘RequestA’.

2.error: cannot convert ‘int*’ to ‘Request*’ in return.

3.error: expected ‘;’ before ‘RequestA’.

4.error: ‘RequestA’ was not declared in this scope.

5.error: ‘else’ without a previous ‘if’
```

Request is parent class of RequestA, MRRequest and RequestB.

These files I'm including:

```
1.#include "../../../include/request/Request.h"

2.#include "../../include/request/RequestA.h"

3.#include "../../include/request/RequestB.h"
```

and many more

```
RequestA.h

#ifndef REQUESTA_H_
#define REQUESTA_H_

#include "../../../include/request/Request.h"
#include "../../../../include/common/GsmMeasurements.h"

class RequestA : public Request
{
    public:
        enum { TYPE = 1 , MAX_DATA_LEN = 10 };

        RequestA( );
        virtual ~RequestA( );

        virtual int get_type( ) const;
        virtual void * get_data( ) ;
        virtual const void * get_data( ) const ;

        virtual int get_length( ) const;
        virtual void set_length( int length );

    private:

        char data_[MAX_DATA_LEN + 1];
        int data_length_;
};


#endif /* REQUESTA_H_ */

Request.h

#ifndef REQUEST_H_
#define REQUEST_H_

#include "../../../include/common/GsmMeasurements.h"

class Request
{
    public:
        virtual ~Request( ){}

        virtual int get_type( ) const = 0;
        virtual void * get_data( ) = 0;
        virtual const void * get_data( ) const = 0;

        virtual int get_length ( ) const = 0;
        virtual void set_length( int length ) = 0;

};

#endif /* REQUEST_H_ */
```

Comment: How are your classes defined?

Comment: We cannot help unless you show relevant parts of `Request.h` and `RequestA.h` and `RequestB.h`

Comment: Thought about using `switch`?

Comment: Check your header guards in RequestA.h, Request.h and RequestB.h; It's a mistake I commonly make.

Comment: RequestA.h and RequestB.h almost same

Comment: @nishantjr you are right problem is in Header guards Thank you. please type this as an Answer so i can accept you answer Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your header guards in RequestA.h, RequestB.h and Request.h

It's a mistake I commonly make.

Comment: Good catch, I'll have to remember this one.

Comment: @user1567453 The first time it happened I wasted at least an hour trying to figure it out... you don't forget a lesson like that ;)